# Universal sentence encoder fr-en TF 2.x

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I saw the english-french USE model for TF 1.x at : https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-xling/en-fr/1

Would this model be available for TF 2.x ? I couldn't find an upgrade.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can find all models for TF 2.x which were trained on French text at this link: https://tfhub.dev/s?language=fr&tf-version=tf2

One of the resulting models is [USE multilingual large v3](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3) that can be used like so:

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_text

english_sentences = ["dog", "Puppies are nice.", "I enjoy taking long walks along the beach with my dog."]
french_sentences = ["chien", "Les chiots sont gentils.", "J'aime faire de longues promenades sur la plage avec mon chien."]

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3")

en_result = embed(english_sentences)
fr_result = embed(french_sentences)

np.inner(en_result, fr_result)
# array([[0.99073195, 0.3755554 , 0.2772888 ],
#        [0.40345296, 0.8896688 , 0.30821913],
#        [0.26346597, 0.2500368 , 0.8951807 ]], dtype=float32)
```